# jasmine can not mock the elasticsearch object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, elasticsearch, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm implementing an application using yoeman, grunt, angular, grunt-jasmine, karma, elasticsearch. I need to write a test for my custom service (names elasticSearchService) which call elasticsearch (elasticsearch.angular.js) to search something and return to a promise but i can not mock that elasticsearch (esFactory) object.

### packages.json

```
"karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
```

### bower.json

```
"elasticsearch": "~2.4.1",
```

### my service

```
angular
  .module('tagsearchFrontendApp')
  .factory('elasticSearchService', ['$q', 'esFactory',
    function ($q, esFactory) {

      var client = esFactory({
        host: 'localhost:9200'
      });

      var search = function (term, offset) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var query = {
          'match': {
            '_all': term
          }
        };
        client.search({
          'index': 'recipes',
          'type': 'recipe',
          'body': {
            'size': 10,
            'from': (offset || 0) * 10,
            'query': query
          }
        }).then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          var ii = 0,
            hits_in, hits_out = [];
          hits_in = (result.hits || {}).hits || [];
          for (; ii < hits_in.length; ii++) {
            hits_out.push(hits_in[ii]);
          }
          deferred.resolve(hits_out);
        }, deferred.reject);

        return deferred.promise;
      };
....
```

### My test

```
describe('elasticSearchService test', function () {

  var _elasticSearchService, rootScope, q;

  beforeEach(module('tagsearchFrontendApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(['$q', '$rootScope', 'esFactory', 'elasticSearchService', function ($q, $rootScope, esFactory, elasticSearchService) {

    _elasticSearchService = elasticSearchService;
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    q = $q;

    spyOn(esFactory, "search").andCallFake(function () {
      console.log("elasticsearch: fake search");
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve('The fake search resolve');
      console.log(deferred.promise);
      return deferred.promise;
    });
  }]));

  it('search okay', function () {
    _elasticSearchService.search('Developer', 1).then(function(){
       ...
    });
  });
});
```

After executing "grunt test", an error message occurs "search() method does not exist" although my app runs the search function okay with the elasicsearch factory. Could you help me resolve this bug?

Comment: did you mean to spy on _elasticSearchService instead of esFactory? Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: No, I mean that spy on esFactory because my service (elasticSearchService) injects esFactory (from elasticsearch.angular.js) and call its search function.

the error message is "search() method does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$provide` at configuration time to replace your service by a mock one

```
describe('elasticSearchService test', function () {

    var esMock;
    var service;

    beforeEach(module('tagsearchFrontendApp') , function ($provide){
        $provide.factory('esFactory',function(){
            return function(){
                return esMock;
            }
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($q,elasticSearchService){
        esMock={
           search:function(){
            return $q.when('The fake search resolve');
           }
        };
        service=elasticSearchService;
    }));

    it('should search with elastic search',function(){
        spyOn(esMock, 'search').andCallThrough();
        _elasticSearchService.search('Developer', 1).then(function(result){
           ...
        });
    });
});
```

You might need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` to resolve the promise it your test, not sure.

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'esMock'). Could you plz illustrate more pactifularly ?

Comment: see the edit. Difficult to spot these kind of issues without a actual running code. [here](https://github.com/blog-it/blog-it-app/blob/master/public/spec/test/MarkdownSpec.js) is a working example of the technique

Comment: Thank you for your feedback soon but here has a special case: var client = esFactory({host: 'localhost:9200'});. After modifying source code as you suggested, a new error message is [object Object]' is not a function (evaluating 'esFactory({host:'localhost:9200'})').

Comment: See the edit. Of course your mock has to follow the same interface than the real function: your esFactory return a function which returns a service(with the search function), your mocks have to be the same. But I think you can troubleshoot these errors yourself !

Answer (score 0):

Since you create an instance of the esFactory the search function in a prototype function. In your spy do the following

```
spyOn(esFactory.prototype, 'search')...
```

And you'll be in business.

Another observation is there is no need to inject q and make a deferred in your service. You can just return the promise created by the esFactory client search function and then in your handler return the value instead of resolving the deferred.